# Faulty primary /sda, Secondary /sdb won't load right?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

Production linux server issue:

Primary drive faulty, took secondary drive and installed to another server using SCSI drives, installed as secondary.

Want to restore cpanel backup files to primary on that 2nd server but have a major problem:

First, it shows /backup correctly but it shows 99MB??? Its a 300GB SCSI drive.

```
root@server [~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3             271G  158G  101G  62% /
/dev/sda1              99M   36M   59M  38% /boot
none                  2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb1              99M   56M   39M  60% /backup
/usr/tmpDSK           4.9G   55M  4.6G   2% /tmp
/tmp                  4.9G   55M  4.6G   2% /var/tmp
```

Also, I just do a grep sdb /var/log/dmesg and get a bunch of these

```
Buffer I/O error on device sdb3, logical block 577295729
Buffer I/O error on device sdb3, logical block 577295730
Buffer I/O error on device sdb3, logical block 577295731
Buffer I/O error on device sdb3, logical block 577295732
Buffer I/O error on device sdb3, logical block 577295733
Buffer I/O error on device sdb3, logical block 577295734
```

The /backup directory shows these files!

```
root@server [/backup]# ls -lh
total 50M
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 7.0K Sep 22 23:54 ./
drwxr-xr-x  30 root root 4.0K Oct 29 22:17 ../
-rwxr--r--   1 root root 6.0K Nov 20  2007 aquota.user*
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  51K Feb 18  2011 config-2.6.9-100.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  51K Jul 21 16:38 config-2.6.9-101.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  50K Jan 14  2009 config-2.6.9-78.0.13.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  51K Aug  5  2008 config-2.6.9-78.0.1.EL
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  50K Aug  5  2008 config-2.6.9-78.0.1.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  50K Apr 30  2009 config-2.6.9-78.0.22.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  51K Oct  8  2008 config-2.6.9-78.0.5.EL
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  50K Nov 19  2008 config-2.6.9-78.0.8.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  51K Sep 15  2009 config-2.6.9-89.0.11.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  51K Nov  3  2009 config-2.6.9-89.0.16.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  51K Jan  8  2010 config-2.6.9-89.0.19.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  51K Mar 17  2010 config-2.6.9-89.0.23.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  51K May  6  2010 config-2.6.9-89.0.25.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  51K Aug 24  2009 config-2.6.9-89.0.9.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  51K Oct 19  2010 config-2.6.9-89.31.1.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  51K Dec  2  2010 config-2.6.9-89.33.1.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  51K Jan 18  2011 config-2.6.9-89.35.1.ELsmp
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 1.0K Sep 22 23:54 grub/
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 664K Apr 20  2011 initrd-2.6.9-100.ELsmp.img
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 664K Sep 22 23:54 initrd-2.6.9-101.ELsmp.img
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 662K Jan 21  2009 initrd-2.6.9-78.0.13.ELsmp.img
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 671K Sep 27  2008 initrd-2.6.9-78.0.1.EL.img
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 662K Sep 15  2008 initrd-2.6.9-78.0.1.ELsmp.img
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 662K May  4  2009 initrd-2.6.9-78.0.22.ELsmp.img
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 671K Nov  9  2008 initrd-2.6.9-78.0.5.EL.img
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 662K Jan 12  2009 initrd-2.6.9-78.0.8.ELsmp.img
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 663K Sep 24  2009 initrd-2.6.9-89.0.11.ELsmp.img
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 663K Nov 17  2009 initrd-2.6.9-89.0.16.ELsmp.img
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 663K Jan 28  2010 initrd-2.6.9-89.0.19.ELsmp.img
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 663K Mar 28  2010 initrd-2.6.9-89.0.23.ELsmp.img
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 663K Jun 29  2010 initrd-2.6.9-89.0.25.ELsmp.img
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 663K Aug 31  2009 initrd-2.6.9-89.0.9.ELsmp.img
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 663K Nov  6  2010 initrd-2.6.9-89.31.1.ELsmp.img
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 663K Dec 27  2010 initrd-2.6.9-89.33.1.ELsmp.img
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 663K Feb 28  2011 initrd-2.6.9-89.35.1.ELsmp.img
drwx------   2 root root  12K Jul 17  2006 lost+found/
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 9.2K Aug 12  2006 message
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 9.2K Aug 12  2006 message.ja
-rwxr--r--   1 root root   32 Nov 20  2007 quota.user*
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  67K Feb 18  2011 symvers-2.6.9-100.ELsmp.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  67K Jul 21 16:38 symvers-2.6.9-101.ELsmp.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  67K Sep 15  2009 symvers-2.6.9-89.0.11.ELsmp.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  67K Nov  3  2009 symvers-2.6.9-89.0.16.ELsmp.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  67K Jan  8  2010 symvers-2.6.9-89.0.19.ELsmp.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  67K Mar 17  2010 symvers-2.6.9-89.0.23.ELsmp.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  67K May  6  2010 symvers-2.6.9-89.0.25.ELsmp.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  67K Aug 24  2009 symvers-2.6.9-89.0.9.ELsmp.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  67K Oct 19  2010 symvers-2.6.9-89.31.1.ELsmp.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  67K Dec  2  2010 symvers-2.6.9-89.33.1.ELsmp.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  67K Jan 18  2011 symvers-2.6.9-89.35.1.ELsmp.gz
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   17 Sep 30  2006 System.map -> System.map-2.6.18
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 770K Feb 18  2011 System.map-2.6.9-100.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 770K Jul 21 16:38 System.map-2.6.9-101.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 779K Jan 14  2009 System.map-2.6.9-78.0.13.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 762K Aug  5  2008 System.map-2.6.9-78.0.1.EL
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 779K Aug  5  2008 System.map-2.6.9-78.0.1.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 779K Apr 30  2009 System.map-2.6.9-78.0.22.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 762K Oct  8  2008 System.map-2.6.9-78.0.5.EL
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 779K Nov 19  2008 System.map-2.6.9-78.0.8.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 768K Sep 15  2009 System.map-2.6.9-89.0.11.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 768K Nov  3  2009 System.map-2.6.9-89.0.16.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 768K Jan  8  2010 System.map-2.6.9-89.0.19.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 768K Mar 17  2010 System.map-2.6.9-89.0.23.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 768K May  6  2010 System.map-2.6.9-89.0.25.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 768K Aug 24  2009 System.map-2.6.9-89.0.9.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 768K Oct 19  2010 System.map-2.6.9-89.31.1.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 768K Dec  2  2010 System.map-2.6.9-89.33.1.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 768K Jan 18  2011 System.map-2.6.9-89.35.1.ELsmp
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   14 Sep 30  2006 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-2.6.18
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.5M Feb 18  2011 vmlinuz-2.6.9-100.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.5M Jul 21 16:38 vmlinuz-2.6.9-101.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.5M Jan 14  2009 vmlinuz-2.6.9-78.0.13.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.5M Aug  5  2008 vmlinuz-2.6.9-78.0.1.EL
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.5M Aug  5  2008 vmlinuz-2.6.9-78.0.1.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.5M Apr 30  2009 vmlinuz-2.6.9-78.0.22.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.5M Oct  8  2008 vmlinuz-2.6.9-78.0.5.EL
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.5M Nov 19  2008 vmlinuz-2.6.9-78.0.8.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.5M Sep 15  2009 vmlinuz-2.6.9-89.0.11.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.5M Nov  3  2009 vmlinuz-2.6.9-89.0.16.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.5M Jan  8  2010 vmlinuz-2.6.9-89.0.19.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.5M Mar 17  2010 vmlinuz-2.6.9-89.0.23.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.5M May  6  2010 vmlinuz-2.6.9-89.0.25.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.5M Aug 24  2009 vmlinuz-2.6.9-89.0.9.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.5M Oct 19  2010 vmlinuz-2.6.9-89.31.1.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.5M Dec  2  2010 vmlinuz-2.6.9-89.33.1.ELsmp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.5M Jan 18  2011 vmlinuz-2.6.9-89.35.1.ELsmp
```

Comment: `code`root@server2 [~]# umount /backup
root@server2 [~]# mount /dev/sdb3 /backup
`code`
It halted the server when I ran the mount.

Notice the errors says “sdb3” not “sdb1” as shown in the original df –h output, which explains the 99MB usage instead of over 30GB. However, now the question is how to do we mount this and correct the I/O errors – WITHOUT formatting that backup drive.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at a `/boot` partition there.  That, combined with the errors on the drive, makes me think you've put the old primary drive in this server, not the old secondary drive.

Before you pull it back out, check `/proc/partitions` and try mounting some of the other partitions on `sdb` to see what they have on them.  I'd steer clear of that sdb3 though.

Comment: 'code'root@server2 [~]# umount /backup
root@server2 [~]# mount /dev/sdb3 /backup'code'

It halted the server when I ran the mount.

Notice the errors says “sdb3” not “sdb1” as shown in the original df –h output, which explains the 99MB usage instead of over 30GB. However, now the question is how to do we mount this and correct the I/O errors – WITHOUT formatting that backup drive.

Comment: @FaithInUnseenThings that's what data recovery centers are paid the big bucks to do.  In the meantime, you could try `ddrescue` to make an image of as much of the partition as possible, then depending on the filesystem, a tool like `debug2fs` to read the image.